# Zuul connection pool size

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I have a question about configuring the size of the connection pool when using Zuul by itself, and not using Ribbon or other Netflix components.

We have a system that uses Zuul to proxy requests to a Mule server. We are only using Zuul and not Ribbon. We have defined 4 routes that call the Mule services. One of these services is long running, probably around 3 seconds per call.

When we load the system with 40 simultaneous users we get this error

```
org.apache.http.conn.ConnectionPoolTimeoutException: Timeout waiting for connection from pool
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute.getEntryBlocking(ConnPoolByRoute.java:412)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute$1.getPoolEntry(ConnPoolByRoute.java:298)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager$1.getConnection(ThreadSafeClientConnManager.java:238)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:423)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:115)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.SimpleHostRoutingFilter.forwardRequest(SimpleHostRoutingFilter.java:262)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.SimpleHostRoutingFilter.forward(SimpleHostRoutingFilter.java:225)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.SimpleHostRoutingFilter.run(SimpleHostRoutingFilter.java:177)
    at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.runFilter(ZuulFilter.java:112)
```

When I looked through the code to figure out how to change the size of the connection pool and found this code

```
private static ClientConnectionManager newConnectionManager() throws Exception {
    KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    trustStore.load(null, null);
    SSLSocketFactory sf = new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
    sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
    SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
    registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
    registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));
    ThreadSafeClientConnManager cm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(registry);
    cm.setMaxTotal(Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("zuul.max.host.connections", "200")));
    cm.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("zuul.max.host.connections", "20")));
    return cm;
}
```

At first I thought all I have to do is increase the value for zuul.max.host.connections and that would increase the size of per route max, but then I noticed that the same system property is used to set the total max number of connections.

Is setting the value of this system parameter the correct way to control the pool sizes? Or should we be using another component such as Ribbon to better manage these connections?

Comment: If setting `-dzuul.max.host.connections` works, I'd go with that.

Comment: @stephen-inzer did you able to find any solution on this issue ?

Answer (score 3):

you can config

```
zuul.host.maxTotalConnections=1000
zuul.host.maxPerRouteConnections=100
```

Answer (score 1):

If you still looking for solution, i took the following approach.

1- Disable ( SimpleHostRoutingFilter ) by passing 
( -Dzuul.SimpleHostRoutingFilter.route.disable=true ) as system property.

2- Write your own customized Routing filter, in my case i copied ( SimpleHostRoutingFilter ), and make some modification to be able to set these properties .